# how to set IIS6 logfile location

Tags: iis-6, wsh, logfiles

I have tried this:

```
     c:\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/logfiledirectory d:\logfiles\iis6
```

on our Windows Server 2003 machine but there is an error :

```
       Windows Script Host
       This script does not work with WScript.
         [OK]
```

How do I set the location?

Answer (score 2):

Use cscript....

You could use a command like

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/logfiledirectory d:\logfiles\iis6
```

or set cscript as the default host for vbscript.